# vim colorscheme executing but not changing colors

Tags: vim

I have installed a color scheme called `ashen.vim` to my `~/.vimrc/colors` folder. When I am in vim I am able to execute the color scheme by doing `:colorscheme ashen`, but the actual colors of the file do not change at all. (Color scheme downloaded from http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/html/index-java.html ). Is there something else I need to do to 'activate' the color scheme?

Comment: Is the terminal you're using capable of displaying the colors? Which terminal are you using? What does "$ echo $TERM" return?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably need to tell vim to use 256 colors.  Add:

```
" 256-color terminal
set t_Co=256
```

To the top of your ~/.vimrc.  Of course, if your terminal does not support 256 colors, this isn't really going to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is very important to add these lines at the TOP of the .vimrc file or it won't work. Even if you have set it in your Iterm2 settings.